# How to assign an error message to the good text label with FluentValidaiton in my xamarin.forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fluentvalidation

The user is currently filling a form which has multiple entry. Right now i have a label under each entry which will display the error message if the validation doesn't pass.

My problem is that right now, i am unable to assign the correct error message to the correct label. Because if one error happens and the other doesn't, i get an error that the index doesn't exist which makes sens.

Is it possible ? Note : it's the first time i am using Fluent Validation and the implementation might not be good. So feel free to suggest a better implementation

**I created myself a Validator class which contains the property to which i bind in my UI. Those will be used to display the error message. ( Note they have been defined in BaseViewModel.cs also)**

```
    public class Validator
    {
        public string TasksGroupDescriptionWarning { get; set; }

        public string TasksGroupDateWarning { get; set; }
}
```

**My two entry with their Label assigned to the properties**

```
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Date de calcul:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
        <DatePicker   Date="{Binding TasksGroupDate}" FontFamily="ROBOTO" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" ></DatePicker>
        <Label Text="{Binding TasksGroupDateWarning}" TextColor="#FF0000" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>

    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Description de la journée" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="TasksGroupDescription" Text="{Binding TasksGroupDescription}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding TasksGroupDescriptionWarning}" TextColor="#FF0000" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>

    </StackLayout>
```

**My TasksGroupValidator.cs which validate a TasksGroup object.**

```
public class TasksGroupValidator : AbstractValidator<TasksGroup>
{

    public TasksGroupValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.TasksGroupDescription).NotEmpty().WithMessage("* Veuillez entrer une description.");

        RuleFor(p => p.TasksGroupDate).Must(BeValidDate).WithMessage("* Vous ne pouvez pas entrer une date supérieure à celle d'aujourd'hui.");
    }

    protected bool BeValidDate(DateTime date)
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

        if (date > currentDate)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**This is where i save the form and validate, here if i have the two errors at the same time it will work, but if i only have one of the two, i will get an index error for the second since it doesn't exist**

```
  async Task SaveNewTask()
        {
            // in my code i created a TasksGroup object
            TasksGroupValidator tasksGroupValidator = new TasksGroupValidator();
            
           ValidationResult results = tasksGroupValidator.Validate(tasksGroup);

             if (results.IsValid == false)
            {
        //assign to first label
                TasksGroupDescriptionWarning = results.Errors[0].ErrorMessage;
                validator.TasksGroupDescriptionWarning = TasksGroupDescriptionWarning;
              //assign to second label
                TasksGroupDateWarning = results.Errors[1].ErrorMessage;
                validator.TasksGroupDateWarning = TasksGroupDateWarning;
            }
            //else save to database
         }
```

**EDIT TO GET AN ANSWER IN THE COMMENTS**

```
 public bool Validate(TasksGroup tasksGroup)
        {
            ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(tasksGroup);
            if (!results.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var e in results.Errors)
                {
                    ErrorMessages[e.PropertyName] = e.ErrorMessage;
                }

            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ErrorMessages));
            return results.IsValid;

        }

 
        async Task SaveNewTask()
        {

            
            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Delay(4000);


            IsBusy = false;

            TasksGroup tasksGroup = new TasksGroup();
            Tasks tasks = new Tasks();

            tasksGroup.TasksGroupDescription = TasksGroupDescription;
            tasksGroup.TasksGroupDate = TasksGroupDate;
            tasks.TaskDuration = TaskDuration;
            tasks.TaskDBA = TaskDBA;
            tasks.TaskDescription = TaskDescription;

            tasksGroup.Taches = new List<Tasks>() { tasks };


            if(Validate(tasksGroup))
            {
                await App.Database.SaveTasksGroupAsync(tasksGroup);
 

                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary` to store the validation messages.

Here is a code snip, you can adapt it to your code.

ViewModel:

```
public class TaskGroupViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TaskGroup TaskGroup { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }
    public ICommand ValidateCommand { get; }

    private readonly AbstractValidator<TaskGroup> _validator;

    public TaskGroupViewModel()
    {
        TaskGroup = new TaskGroup();
        ErrorMessages = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        ValidateCommand = new Command(() => Validate());

        _validator = new InlineValidator<TaskGroup>();
        _validator.RuleFor(x => x.TasksGroupDate)
            .Must(x => x > DateTime.Now)
            .WithMessage("* Vous ne pouvez pas entrer une date supérieure à celle d'aujourd'hui.");

        _validator.RuleFor(x => x.TasksGroupDescription)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("* Veuillez entrer une description.");
    }

    public bool Validate()
    {
        ErrorMessages.Clear();

        var result = _validator.Validate(TaskGroup);
        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var e in result.Errors)
            {
                ErrorMessages[e.PropertyName] = e.ErrorMessage;
            }
        }

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ErrorMessages));

        return result.IsValid;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
....
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Date de calcul:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
        <DatePicker   Date="{Binding TaskGroup.TasksGroupDate}" FontFamily="ROBOTO" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" ></DatePicker>
        <Label Text="{Binding ErrorMessages[TasksGroupDate]}" TextColor="#FF0000" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>

    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Description de la journée" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="TasksGroupDescription" Text="{Binding TaskGroup.TasksGroupDescription}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding ErrorMessages[TasksGroupDescription]}" TextColor="#FF0000" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
    </StackLayout>

    <Button Text="Validate" Command="{Binding ValidateCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>
</StackLayout>
...
```

Comment: Wow thanks for taking the time to write me this out ! This worked but i only have one question, let's say i get two error message and i correct one, and press the command again, it always leave the message even if 1 of them is corrected. Is there a way to prevent that ? ( I would like the message to disapear since it got corrected) idk if i'm clear haha.

Comment: @codejourney I've tested this code here. Each time you press the Validate button, it will run the validation(s), only current errors will be displayed. If a field was corrected, then the error message won't be shown. I dont know if you are using an older SDK. Try setting the TwoWay binding mode `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: I tried TwoWay without success. The only difference is that separated the validate into a function that i call in my saving command to validate the tasksGroup( see code above with the title edit). Do you see any problem there ? Thanks

Comment: @codejourney I think you forgot to clear the `ErrorMessages` dictionary. Check the `Validate` function posted on my answer.